# How can I display thumbnail on hovering the seek bar on videoJS video player from mpd file?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, video.js, ffmpegthumbnailer

I am currently using videojs video player. I am trying to display thumbnail when the user hover over the seek/progress bar.

I am receiving the image URL on the mpd manifest file for the video like this

```
<AdaptationSet contentType="image" mimeType="image/jpeg">
  <SegmentTemplate duration="2" media="$RepresentationID$/$Number$.jpg" startNumber="0" />
  <Representation bandwidth="10000" height="90" id="thumbs" width="160">
    <EssentialProperty schemeIdUri="http://dashif.org/guidelines/thumbnail_tile" value="1x1" />
  </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
```

Please refer this doc for a detailed explanation of in-stream thumbnail support

https://www.theoplayer.com/blog/in-stream-thumbnail-support-dvr-dash-streams

How can I use this to achieve the intended functionality on videojs(7.4.1)

Thanks in advance.